# Foliate can not open epubs

Tags: ebooks, epub, foliate

In Ubuntu 22.04, Foliate doesn't open epubs and gives errors but when I try to open the same epub on the app, book opens but foliate shows text as invisible.

When I tried to copy the text with mouse middle click it copied and pasted.

I saw someone recommended to try with another version, so I tried with the Ubuntu Wayland. In Wayland version it has no problem at all, but my PC freezes on Wayland.

Any help?

Comment: How did you install Foliate? Are you using the Foliate snap? Then using the Foliate PPA or Flatpak may help. Snaps have a lot of permission issues.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Uninstalled it from snap I reinstalled it from snap. It worked for me.